# running windows C++ code on a linux cluster

Tags: c++, linux, windows, cluster-computing

My program recently got an `bad_alloc` error when increasing it's precision. My guess is, that it needs more RAM than my Computer can assign it (effectively more than 3GB RAM needed).
So I decided to try it on our linux cluster since it can give me way more RAM. It contains some gcc modules. But I'm not sure how to use my c++ code on it. Could I just run my .exe on the cluster or should I recompile it first on the linux cluster?

Comment: There are environments (e.g. [WINE](https://www.winehq.org)) which can run *some* Windows executable files. Of you could refactor your code to be portable between Windows and POSIX platforms, and rebuild for Linux. Or you can add more memory to your system (or upgrade your hardware and Windows version to 64 bits so it can use more than 3 GiB in user-space).

Comment: What should I consider when rebuilding it for linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are ways to make Windows executables run on Linux, e.g. [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/) but usually you want a native Linux executable. Executables have a different file format on Windows ([EXE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.exe)) and on Linux ([ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format)).

Your options are

- to recompile the code and run the program without other tools or
- to use a tool, e.g. Wine, that can run Windows executables on Linux.

If your code can be compiled on a different system depends on your code. Did you use Windows libraries? Did you use third party libraries? Did you use compiler extensions?

Most third party libraries can usually be also used on Linux. For Windows-only libraries and compiler extensions you have to find a workaround.

Comment: In order to recompile it: do I need to change certain things in my code, that dont work in linux?

Comment: Thats depends on your code. Did you use Windows libraries? Did you use third party libraries? Did you use compiler extensions?

Comment: during compilation I use the following gcc options in windows:
```gcc -O2 -IC:\Users\hdorn\Desktop\eclipse-workspace\utils -c %1.cc // gcc %1.o -lm -lstdc++ -o %1.exe```
how would this translate to linux? E.g. I'm not sure how to call for the utilities under ```-IC:\Users\hdorn\Desktop\eclipse-workspace\utils```

Comment: What is `%1`? On Linux you don't use filename extensions for executables. Your output would be just `%1` without `.exe`. What is the content of `C:\Users\hdorn\Desktop\eclipse-workspace\utils`? Why do you call `gcc -lstdc++` instead of simply `g++`?

Comment: I just got it to run as intended. I had to put it like this : ```gcc -O2 -Iutils/ -c test.cc // gcc test.o -lm -lstdc++ -o test``` with the utils folder in the same path. Now it magically works fine. Thanks!

Comment: and I couldn't find out anything about ```-lstdc++``` either... it's probably something very old, the original writers have used.

Comment: nevermind, found it: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/

Comment: I recommend to avoid `gcc` in your case. `gcc` usually is used for C projects. `g++` usually is used for C++ project. Of course you can use both programs for both types of projects but `g++` sets C++ specific flags like `-lstdc++` (I don't know if it's the only difference). You can replace `gcc -lstdc++` with `g++`. The compiler is chossen by source filename extension (.c, .cc, .cpp, ...)

Comment: would the executable ```test``` work on the cluster if it does not have ```g++``` installed (or is it contained in gcc)? Is it enough if I copy the executable ```test``` on the cluster to run it, or do I need to recompile it there from my .cc?

Comment: Where did you build the executable `test`? I've never seen a system with `gcc` but without `g++`. It's usually in the same package.

Comment: okey, thanks. I will just try. I compiled/linked it on my ubuntu subsystem (win10 microsoft store ubuntu version)

Comment: It can work but if all dynamic dependencies have the same ABI. If the ABI is different this can cause wrong results or program crashes.

Comment: Recompiling on the cluster again is needed, but it works! :D And there seems to be no difference between g++ or gcc -lstdc++

Answer (score 1):

Well, you definitely need to recompile your code on cluster, if I understood the situation correctly. You have built your app on Windows platform, so that binary cannot work on linux target system.